# controller and action of twitters main page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, controller, action

Just speculating as to what controller/action twitters main page is, when logged in. The page where you can view tweets and create your own.

I would guess controller: tweet, action: index

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's your generic controller/action page.

There's a section to view the tweets you have (`tweets#index`) and there is another to create tweets (`tweets#new`). There is also a button to delete tweets (`tweets#delete`). And there are some other actions I would not continue to list so this reply does not become a documentation. But you get the idea.